How to assign style variants to the simplebox demo widget of CKEditor 5?
I have successfully implemented the simple box demo widget and am now trying to offer different variants (classes) of the simple box, which can then be selected via styles, for example.
The result should then look like this:
<section class="simple-box variant-class">
    <h1 class="simple-box-title">Box title</h1>
    <div class="simple-box-description">
        <p>The description goes here.</p>
    </div>
</section>

I couldn't manage it with the usual "style definitions". In CKEditor 4 I solved this with CKEDITOR.dialogue.add[...] and made the class available for selection there, but that no longer exists.
Interim status:
After some research, I had considered replicating the functionality of the ImageStyle plugin, which also offers variants for image alignment, but this all seems to be very complicated and time-consuming. As a workaround, I therefore set up a separate widget for each required variant and then used the "grouping toolbar items in dropdowns" feature to display their buttons with individual icons.
